# Manually editing post after I approved an edit but before it's approved by others leads to weird results

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27435648/41071), I approved [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6460627). But before the edit was approved by enough people to be applied, I decided to make an edit of my own; basically I changed my mind from "Approve" to "Improve Edit".

But there is no way to do that in the UI, so I tried to use the edit URL directly (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27435648/edit). There, I saw the post with the suggested edit applied, so I assumed my making by changes, I would force approve the edit. But instead, it force rejected it.

I find this behavior really weird. Among other things, it potentially breaks the attribution requirement of CC.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to edit it directly like that.  Though I've done it too.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Yeah, I know. But then SO shouldn't let me do that.